# How to delete files from local system without deleting them from github repo?

Tags: git, github

I would like to keep files in github repo, but not on the local system.

After some searches, I can only find the solution to the other way around: delete in github repo, not local.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+files+locally+but+not+remote

Comment: if the file is already pushed, you can also add the path to the `.gitignore` so you can delete it locally and git file ignore changes made to this file.